# Where to put robots.txt in tomcat 7?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, sitemap, robots.txt

I'm using Tomcat 7 to host my application. 
I've used a ROOT.xml file under tomcat-home\conf\Catalina\localhost

```
<Context 
  docBase="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\mywebapp\MyApplication" 
  path="" 
  reloadable="true" 
/>
```

This is to load my webapp in the root context.

But now I'm confused as to where to put the `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` files. When I put in under C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\mywebapp\MyApplication, it doesn't show up.

I've also tried placing it inside `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT` , just in case. But nothing works. I'm still getting 404 not found.
Can anyone please guide.

p.s. My web application runs fine. It's just that my `robots.txt` file is unreachable.

### EDIT

My web.xml file:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be in your context directory

`mywebapp\MyApplication`

just where you will have your web-inf directory,index.html etc.

UPDATE:

As per our discussion all urls are handled by Spring MVC DelegatingFilterProxy , so you need to exclude *.txt from this filter somehow, may be by extending DelegatingFilterProxy  and configuring that filter in web.xml

SOLUTION: I can server static content through this hack in Spring MVC:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/robots.txt" location="/robots.txt" order="0"/>
```

Saved me a ton of headache. :) Writing it for anyone else to benefit from.

Comment: I've put it there, but it still gives me 404.

Comment: what is the link where you get 404? is it `http://serverip:port/robots.txt` ? if so `http://serverip:port/index.html` is it loading

Comment: Yes, http://serverip:port loads. I've my home page file under WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp and when I goto http://serverip:port, it loads.

Comment: can you post your web.xml to see if you have any special mapping

Comment: Let me update the question, so that the web.xml is more viewable.

Comment: ok problem is `<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>` all requests are routed through DelegatingFilterProxy

Comment: instead of /* can you add specific types like *.html/*.htm/*.do etc, so that *.txt is not filtered

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21177/discussion-between-littlelebowski-and-subin-s)

Comment: its not a hack, its the normal method for serving static content

Comment: I followed your answer but I cannot access it yet. My question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302465/i-cannot-access-robots-txt-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 6):

Just put the `robots.txt` in `Tomcat_DIR/webapps/ROOT/`

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue: I doesn't meter where I put my robots.txt or configure `<mvc:resources mapping="/robots.txt" location="/robots.txt" order="0"/>` each request to robots.txt returned 404 status.

Problem here is that I use both Spring MVC and Backbone.js MVC on client side, which has its routing. So I couldn't adjust `<url-pattern></url-pattern>` to serve both MVCs.

The only quick and ugly solution I found here is to process requests to /robots.txt as a request in Spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/robots.txt", produces = {"text/plain"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getRobotsTxt() {
    return "User-agent: *" + 
   "\n" + "Allow: /js/views/*.js" + 
   "\n" + "Allow: /js/*.js" + 
   "\n" + "Allow: /css/*.css" + 
   "\n" + "Allow: /css/*.png" + 
   "\n" + "Disallow: /cgi-bin" + 
   "\n" + "Sitemap: http://blabla/sitemap.xml";
}
```