# I cannot access Robots.txt in Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-hosting, robots.txt

I am trying to give access to `robots.txt` in Spring-MVC. To test the code, I put `robots.txt` in `WebContent`,`Root` and `WEB-INF` but I cannot access to any of them.

I've already applied answers of these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786115/spring-mvc-website-on-root),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891284/where-to-put-robots-txt-in-tomcat-7),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984607/where-to-put-robots-txt-file?rq=1) to no avail.

**MyCode**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/robots.txt" location="/robots.txt" order="0" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Put it in `webapp`

Do you have Spring Security setup?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan No I do not have that setup.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan If I put that in webapp how to give access to that? do I need to configure anything in my Spring application or Tomcat? I have a test.jsp file in my root folder which I can access but not this robots.txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

Put `robots.txt` directly under `webapp`

In `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` have:

`<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>`

`<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/"  />`

Use maven to build your war

Comment: would robots.txt be available on www.domain.com/robots.txt? does that mean you are mapping /resources/** to two different locations? / and /Meta-INF/.... ?

Comment: Hi, how to configure the same using Java configs instead of xml configs? Thanks.